# Ignore specific url from Cloudflare ddos protection

Tags: api, oauth, cloudflare

Is it possible to ignore specific urls (`example.com/oauth/*`, `example.com/api/*`) from Cloudlfare DDoS protection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Page Rules to apply specific settings to individual URL's (including wildcard paths) -

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-